# Python reading lines in a txt file and writing to new txt file

Tags: python-3.x

```
# Inside amazon.py, write Python code to read in the contents of the textfile 'input.txt', and for each line in input.txt.
# Write out a new line in a new text file output.txt that computes the answer to some operation on a list of numbers.

# If the input.txt file has the following:
#    min: 1,2,3,5,6
#    max: 1,2,3,5,6
#    avg: 1,2,3,5,6

# Your program should generate an output.txt file as following:


#    The min of [1, 2, 3, 5, 6] is 1
#    The max of [1, 2, 3, 5, 6] is 6
#    The avg of [1, 2, 3, 5, 6] is 3.4


# Assume that the only operations given in the input file are 'min', 'max' and 'avg', and that the operation is always followed by a list of comma separated integers. 
# Your program should handle any combination of operations, any lengths of input numbers. You can assume that the list of input numbers are always valid ints, and is never empty.
```

I have tried reading all the lines separately. Then writing them out correctly , individually. So far I have tried line splitting and putting the lines in fields of there own... I am just lost.

```
file = open("input.txt","r", encoding='utf8')

data = ""

for line in file:

  #Let's split the line into an array called "fields" using the " " as a separator:
  fields = line.split(":")
  #and let's extract the data:
  Min = fields[0]
  Max = fields[1]
  Avg = fields[2]

  data += "\t" + Min + "\n" + "\t" + str(Max) + "\n" + "\t" + Avg

  print(data)
  file.close()
```

I expect the output txt file to write it like this. But the code should be able to handle any integers.

```
#    The min of [1, 2, 3, 5, 6] is 1
#    The max of [1, 2, 3, 5, 6] is 6
#    The avg of [1, 2, 3, 5, 6] is 3.4
```

Comment: What is the output of the current code?

Comment: Can you clarify your confusion? Why are you for example doing ``Avg = fields[2]`` in the first place -- the operator is defined to always be before the ``:`` (i.e. index 0) and there only 2 fields (operator and data) around the ``:``.

Comment: @98Ed (Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\mulle\Dropbox\Jaco Muller-36289\Introduction to Programming\Task 20\amazon.py", line 37, in <module>
    Avg = fields[2]
IndexError: list index out of range)   The error message is in (). That is the code output.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I'm trying to read the lines separately with their values. So I can write them to the output txt file separately with their correct code and output formats.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, this should work. If you use python3, put `()` braces around the arguments of `print` calls or it might complain.

```
import numpy as np

with open( 'input.txt' ) as fin :
    text = fin.read()

for line in text.split('\n') :
    op, nums = line.split(':')
    op = op.strip()   # remove possible spaces
    nums = map( float, nums.strip().split(',') )

    print 'The', op, 'of', nums, 'is',
    if op == 'avg' :
        print np.mean(nums)
    elif op == 'min' :
        print min(nums)
    elif op == 'max' :
        print max(nums)
    else :
        print 'wrong operation'
```

Comment: @ lenik hi the code you wrote gives a strange message.                                   The min of <map object at 0x035A6BB0> is wrong operation
The max of <map object at 0x035A6B90> is 6.0
The avg of <map object at 0x035A6BB0> is wrong operation            That is the output of the code with print() functions filled.
>>>

Comment: you may replace `nums = map( float, nums.strip().split(',') )` with `nums = list(map( float, nums.strip().split(',') ))` if you're using python3

Comment: @ lenik. Hi the code with the replaced nums = list(map( float, nums.strip().split(',') )) works. But it gives wrong operation for min and avg instead of the required output.

Comment: @JacoMuller could you please provide the correct output and the output you get?

Comment: @ lenik The min of [1, 2, 3, 5, 6] is 1
The max of [1, 2, 3, 5, 6] is 6
The avg of [1, 2, 3, 5, 6] is 3.4          Thats what the output should be.

Comment: @ lenik this is what I get. The min of [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0] is
wrong operation
The max of [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0] is
6.0
The avg of [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0] is
wrong operation                   I don't mind the decimals. It's just the program gives wrong operation instead of the answers to the lists.

Comment: @JacoMuller could you please change `print 'wrong operation'` into `print 'wrong operation', op`, and tell me the resulting output ?

Comment: @ lenik The min of [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0] is
wrong operation min
The max of [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0] is
6.0
The avg of [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0] is
wrong operation avg     thats the new output.

Comment: @JacoMuller please, replace `abs` with `avg`, add somewhere in the beginning `import numpy as np` and replace `print abs` with `print np.mean` -- seems like I mistaken `avg` and `abs` in my original post.

Comment: @JacoMuller you may accept an answer, if you like to =)

Comment: yeah I am new to this. One last quick question how would one write all that to a different txt file. Like the input.txt file and then write the answers to output.txt. How would one go by doing that...?

Comment: @JacoMuller you may open a file: `output = open( 'output.txt', 'w')`, then in every print statement use `print >>output, ...` and finally `output.close()` to close the file.

Comment: print >> output,('The', op, 'of', nums, 'is',)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for >>: 'builtin_function_or_method' and '_io.TextIOWrapper'. Did you mean "print(<message>, file=<output_stream>)"? That is the error.

Comment: @JacoMuller `print( >>output, ...)` ?

Comment: output= open('output.txt' , 'w')

print(>>output,'The', op, 'of', nums, 'is',)
if op == 'avg':
        print ( >>output,np.mean(nums))
elif op == 'min':
        print ( >>output,min(nums))
elif op == 'max':
        print ( >>output,max(nums))
else:
        print ( >>output,'wrong operation')     If i run it like this it keeps giving syntax error on the second > at the first print.

Comment: @JacoMuller seems this has changed in python3, you have to use `print( file=output, .... )` to print to the file

Comment: right your file=output worked great. thanks for all the help